# OpenSSL encryption/decryption remove multiple white spaces to only one

Tags: encryption, plsql, openssl

I have an issue trying to use openssl command to encrypt and decrypt varchar2 variables with text data and multiples white spaces between.

I can encrypt/decrypt, but the output remove multiple white spaces inside the decrypted text. I've tried several ways process the text with urlencode/urldecode and base64encode/base64decode. But the decrypted text is always the same. Maybe white spaces doesn't matter for openssl or what I am doing wrong?

[image]

--Code:

```sql
--Encrypt 
 DECLARE  
  l_output    DBMS_OUTPUT.chararr;
  l_lines      INTEGER := 1000;   
  key_value    VARCHAR2(200) := 'thisisthekeytoencryptdecrypt';
  command      VARCHAR2(1000);
  text_encrypt VARCHAR2(1000);
  text_value   VARCHA2(50):= '11 22      444';

 BEGIN
    command:='echo '||texto_value||'|/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -base64 -A -pass pass:'||key_value;
    host_command(comand);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines(l_output, l_lines);
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_lines LOOP      
      text_encrypt:=text_encrypt||substr(l_output(i),14);
    END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('text_Encrypted:'|| text_encrypt);
END; 
/--


--Decrypt
 DECLARE  
  l_output    DBMS_OUTPUT.chararr;
  l_lines      INTEGER := 1000;   
  key_value    VARCHAR2(200) := 'thisisthekeytoencryptdecrypt';
  command      VARCHAR2(1000);
  text_encrypt VARCHAR2(1000) := 'U2FsdGVkX19ljEkuiUDkNthSfcboezhyYg6+wLO3HC8=';
  text_value   VARCHAR2(50);

 BEGIN
    command:='echo '||text_encrypt||'|/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -base64 -A -pass pass:'||key_value;
    host_command(command);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines(l_output, l_lines);
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_lines LOOP      
      text_value:=text_value||substr(l_output(i),14);
    END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('text_decrypted:'|| text_value);
END; 
/

--host_command: java stored procedure
-- https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql

CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Host" AS
import java.io.*;
public class Host {
  public static void executeCommand(String command) {
    try {
      String[] finalCommand;
      if (isWindows()) {
        finalCommand = new String[4];
        // Use the appropriate path for your windows version.
        //finalCommand[0] = "C:\\winnt\\system32\\cmd.exe";    // Windows NT/2000
        finalCommand[0] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";    // Windows XP/2003
        //finalCommand[0] = "C:\\windows\\syswow64\\cmd.exe";  // Windows 64-bit
        finalCommand[1] = "/y";
        finalCommand[2] = "/c";
        finalCommand[3] = command;
      }
      else {
        finalCommand = new String[3];
        finalCommand[0] = "/bin/sh";
        finalCommand[1] = "-c";
        finalCommand[2] = command;
      }

      final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(finalCommand);
      pr.waitFor();

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          BufferedReader br_in = null;
          try {
            br_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String buff = null;
            while ((buff = br_in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Process out :" + buff);
              try {Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            br_in.close();
          }
          catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught printing process output.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            try {
              br_in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
        }
      }).start();

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          BufferedReader br_err = null;
          try {
            br_err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
            String buff = null;
            while ((buff = br_err.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Process err :" + buff);
              try {Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            br_err.close();
          }
          catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught printing process error.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            try {
              br_err.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  }

  public static boolean isWindows() {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") != -1)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

};
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing this through the shell:

```
command:='echo '||texto_value||'|/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -base64 -A -pass pass:'||key_value;
```

The shell is removing the spaces before sending to the `echo` command. You'll need to put quotes around the value, probably along these lines (note placement of `"`):

```
command:='echo "'||texto_value||'"|/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -base64 -A -pass pass:'||key_value;
```